# Grails Controllers - dynamic methods documentation

Tags: grails, controller

I was wondering what is the best way of finding out what dynamic methods are added to certain variables. I don't see it documented in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html) or the javadoc of the controller class.

An example is the params object in a grails controller:

```
params.int('max')
```

The int methods is injected and I'd like to know what extra methods are available for this particular map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my copy of **The Definitive Guide to Grails 2** several days ago and as it is stated here, there are 8 converting methods for primitive types:

> ... Grails provides convenience methods for doing this type of
>   conversion on request parameters. Those methods are available on the
>   `params` object and have names that correspond to all eight of the
>   primitive types defined by Java (`Boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`,
>   `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`). The methods each accept one or
>   two arguments. The first argument is the name of the request parameter
>   that is to be converted, and the optional second argument is a default
>   value that will be returned if a corresponding request parameter
>   cannot be found or if an error occurs during the conversion ...

And there is also mentioned a converting method named `list`:

> ... Another type of converting method is named `list`. The `list` method is useful
>   when dealing with multiple request parameters of the same name ...

Brown, J. S., Rocher, G., (2013). *The Definitive Guide to Grails 2*. New York: Apress.

ISBN:978-1-4302-4377-9

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430243775)

I hope it's not against any copyright to cite from it...

And yes, I consider books a great source for questions that go a little further and I definitely would recommend **The Definitive Guide to Grails 2** to you or any other programmer who wants to gain a deeper understanding on Grails. Also, the [Grails Mailing Lists](http://grails.org/Mailing+lists) and the [Groovy Zone](http://groovy.dzone.com/) over at dzone.com are good resources for any Grails related questions and/or news. The [Groovy JDK documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) is also of great help, as @doelleri mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, those methods are poorly documented. The best documentation there is on them is in the [Simple Type Converters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#typeConverters) section of the docs. They are also briefly mentioned in the Release Notes for Grails 1.2, which is perhaps even more unhelpful.

The [Groovy JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) is also a good resource to see what methods Groovy adds to the standard Java classes.